# OpenCV C++ read image and patch NaN Error: Assertion failed (_a.depth() == CV_32F) in patchNaNs

Tags: c++, opencv

I have the following code which read an RGB JPEG image, however, the image sometimes has NaN value so I want to patch it with 0:

```
cv::Mat model = cv::imread(path);
cv::patchNaNs(model, 0.0);
```

I keep getting the following error message:

```
OpenCV(3.4.5) Error: Assertion failed (_a.depth() == CV_32F) in patchNaNs, file 
..../core/src/mathfuncs.cpp, line 1597
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'cv::Exception'
```

What does this error message mean?

Comment: That the image type is not float. Thus the exception. Also RGB JPEG should be filled with integers types, no?

Comment: You can check the [function](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/master/modules/core/src/mathfuncs.cpp) you are using to see your fault.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function requires that the input be 32-bit floating-point.  You can use [`cv::convertTo`](https://docs.opencv.org/master/d3/d63/classcv_1_1Mat.html#adf88c60c5b4980e05bb556080916978b) to convert your image to 32-bit:

```
cv::Mat model = cv::imread(path);
cv::Mat output;
model.convertTo(output, CV_32F);
cv::patchNaNs(model, 0.0);
```

Depending on your use case, you may want to normalise the input values so that they are in the range of `[0-1]` for your uses.  Because of the way you named your image (i.e. `model`), I'm assuming you want to create some classification model, so you can specify an additional scale factor to `cv::convertTo` to scale the values after conversion.  Usually images are 8-bit unsigned integer so dividing by 255 can be done here:

```
cv::Mat model = cv::imread(path);
cv::Mat output;
model.convertTo(output, CV_32F, 1.0f / 255.0f);
cv::patchNaNs(model, 0.0);
```